# What prior art can be cited to refute Apple's claim to have invented Interactive Map?

Tags: layers, apple

In U.S. Patent Application [20130339891](http://appft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=/netahtml/PTO/search-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PG01&s1=20130339891&OS=20130339891&RS=20130339891) Apple Inc. claims "An
interactive capability enables a user to dynamically adjust the
content of an electronic map" as well as "Geospatial applications can
be integrated with the map to provide information pertaining to the
area displayed on the map, and to refine search results to those that
are relevant to the area." Apple seeks to patent these ideas based on a number of claims.

The claims the patent application makes seem overly broad and applicable to many GIS capabilities; starting with "A method for displaying a map on a computing device, Comprising: storing information to be displayed on the map in a memory of the computing device, the stored information comprising a plurality of different layers of information, wherein each layer contains a respective type of information."

Surely there is prior art in many GIS systems that can be cited to refute this claim. Please do so.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is on the wrong site for this question.  This is a question for this http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/5658/interactive-map-is-apple-trying-to-patent-40-year-old-gis-methods-patent-ap

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about patents.

Comment: Although the context is patents, the question is about the history of GIS technology.

Comment: I agree with @whuber that the Question is about the history of GIS technology, and thus on-topic, but there is not just one claim to refute in this patent but a whole host of them.  Consequently, I think this Question needs to be edited to focus on just one of the claims, and then questions about the others researched/asked separately.

Comment: I agree that [patents.stackexchange](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/5658/interactive-map-is-apple-trying-to-patent-40-year-old-gis-methods-patent-ap) is the best place to answer this. Still, I wonder how many _cartographers, database administrators, geographers, programmers, and anyone interested in or using GIS_ who are familiar with examples of prior art as it pertains to _questions concerning geographic information systems and science_ will stumble upon that question to answer it there.